# Showing data in a table using java for back-end and AngularJS for front-end

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, jersey

I am writing for this problem several times as I am not finding a solution and I really need it today before 12 o'clock. I am want to display a table with data taken from database in AngularJS for front-end and jersey RESTful services for back-end. All i got when I run my project in browser is a blank table. I really really need anyone of you to help me with my code.

list_main.js

```
   var myApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);

myApp.controller('BooksController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.bookList = null;
    $scope.resMsg = null;

        $scope.showBookList = function() {
            var urlGetUsers = 'http://localhost:8080/BookCommerce/webapi/list';

            var responEC = $http.get(urlGetUsers, {cache: true, transformResponse: function(data, headersGetter) {
                    try {
                        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);
                        keepGoing = true;
                        return jsonObject;
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        console.log(e);
                        $scope.resMsg = "Error. Cannot Retrieve Data";
                    }
                    return {};
                }});//end ajax 

            responEC.success(function(bookList, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.bookList = bookList;
                if ($scope.bookList == null || $scope.bookList.length == 0) {
                    $scope.resMsg = "No Data";
                }
            });
        };

        $scope.showBookList();

    }]);
```

index2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <title>List Of Books</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></s‌​cript>

        <script src="js/list_main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row" data-ng-controller="BooksController" data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-init="showBookList()" style="margin: 10px;">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">

                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="exampleone">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>Title</th>
                                        <th>Author</th>
                                        <th>Description</th>
                                        <th>Price</th>
                                    </tr>                                    
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr data-ng-repeat="book in bookList">
                                        <td>{{book.book_id}}</td>
                                        <td>{{book.book_title}}</td>
                                        <td>{{book.book_author}}</td>
                                        <td>{{book.book_description}}</td>
                                         <td>{{book.book_price}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

ListDAO.java

```
public class ListDAO {
    public List<Book> findAll() {
        List<Book> list = new ArrayList<Book>();
        Connection c = null;
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM book";
        try {
            c = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();
            Statement s = c.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                list.add(processRow(rs));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            ConnectionHelper.close(c);
        }
        return list;
    }
    protected Book processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setBook_id(rs.getInt("book_id"));
        book.setBook_title(rs.getString("book_title"));
        book.setBook_author(rs.getString("book_author"));
        book.setBook_description(rs.getString("book_description"));
        book.setBook_price(rs.getInt("book_price"));

        return book;
    }

}
```

ListResource.java

```
@Path("/list")



    public class ListResource {

      ListDAO dao=new ListDAO();

        @GET

        @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
        public List<Book> findAll() {
            System.out.println("findAll");
            return dao.findAll();
        }

    }
```

Please HELP me! Thank you!

Comment: Would you specify which specific problem you are faced? Your frontend part looks like able to work. I guess it would be related with your api implementation.

Comment: The data that I want to be displayed in the table, are not showing. Let me send you a screenshot of how it looks like

Comment: Was your request done successful?

Comment: yes the method findAll is displaying in the console but the table is not loaded with data

Comment: Pls, Check `data` in the success callback of your `$http` request. It would help to understand where actually problem is

Comment: How to check it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142884/discussion-between-lilly-and-vlad-dekhanov).

Comment: put console.log(data) in the success callback and post the logs that you are getting in console

Comment: I solved it. I will update my code above. Thank you for your time.